# Media Queries issue with browser

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to load different background pictures depending on the aspect-ratio. I'm using LESS css. The problem is, that I don't get any background-image at all and I can't figure out the problem.

(I know that the css at the moment is nonsense. I was trying to simplyfie my code to get it to work but I couldn't)

This is the LESS css part with the mediaqueries:

```
#page_back {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 1;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% auto;

     @media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
         background-image: url(../../images/front.jpg);
     }
     @media all and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
         background-image: url(../../images/front.jpg);
     }
 }
```

I just figured out that the compiled result is:

```
@media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 1) {
  main #page_back { background-image:url(../../images/front.jpg); }
}
@media all and (max-aspect-ratio: 1) {
  main #page_back { background-image:url(../../images/front.jpg); }
}
```

But in the browser it looks like this:

```
@media not all {
    main #page_back {
         background-image: url("../../images/front.jpg");
    }
}
@media not all {
    main #page_back {
        background-image: url("../../images/front.jpg");
    }
}
```

That explains why I don't see any image BUT why is there a **not** and why is my condition disappeared?

**EDIT**

I was doing some more research:

1. I created this js fiddle to see whether my browser can handle the mediaquery
   http://jsfiddle.net/jnd4f8jd/ **It works!**
2. I changed the wrong mediaquery css in browser during runtime of my project to see whether it will work manually: **It fails!**
3. I took out all other css files to be sure that the problem is not coming from any other css source: **It fails!**
4. Tried an other mediaquery (min-width) **It works!**

--> It seems to be a problem with this specific media query (aspect-ratio)
But it can not be a browser problem because the jsfiddle works as aspected. 
**What could cause a 'aspect-ratio' problem?**

Comment: I'm not aware of any Less compiler that can do such transformation to `not all`, so it's most likely some other tool (minifier?) in your build chain having this issue.

Comment: The result by less compilation seems to work as the compiled result looks as expected. But if I check the media queries in browser (FF, Chrome on linux) I see this: not all ...

Answer (score 1):

Could you get round this problem by using Jquery to apply the CSS rather than media queries? Something like this might do the job?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ViewHeight = $(window).height();
    var ViewWidth = $(window).width();
    var AspectRatio = ViewHeight/ViewWidth;
    if (AspectRatio < 1){
        $("#page_back").css("background-image", "url(../../images/front.jpg)");
    } else {
        $("#page_back").css("background-image", "url(../../images/front.jpg)");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not try your solution as I already worked around my problem by using background-size and an optimized version of my backgroundimage. But your approach would most probably work as I used a similar one in other projects!